# Check if all elements in list have a :ok element

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, list-comprehension

I have one list of tuples like this

```
[
    {:ok, {"0000 0000 "}},
    {:ok, %{AM01: %{"C4" => "1111", "C5" => "1"}}},
    {:ok, %{AM04: %{"C2" => "2222", "C6" => "2"}}}
]
```

The first element of tuple :ok represents the map ok.

How ca n I reduce this list to one list like this

```
[:ok, :ok, :ok]
```

because after this transformation I will check if all ok with Enum.all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the list to convert to a list of atoms, you can just use `Enum.all?/2` immediately.

```
result = [
  {:ok, {"0000 0000 "}},
  {:ok, %{AM01: %{"C4" => "1111", "C5" => "1"}}},
  {:ok, %{AM04: %{"C2" => "2222", "C6" => "2"}}}
]

Enum.all?(result, fn
  {:ok, _} -> true
  _ -> false
end)
```

Answer (score 6):

@JustinWood had demonstrated the most idiomatic [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) approach.

The most idiomatic [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) approach would be probably to use [`Kernel.match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html?#match?/2), which is basically a [syntactic sugar](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/40756137278cd5ee2e182e86265c21f0a248808d/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2825) for two `true`/`false` clauses:

```
Enum.all?(input, &match?({:ok, _}, &1))
#⇒ true
```

---

Getting all `:ok` is usually done with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) list comprehension, which filters and maps in one loop:

```
for {:ok, _} <- input, do: :ok 
#⇒ [:ok, :ok, :ok]
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `match`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2), you can reduce the map like this:

```elixir
Enum.map(foo, &elem(&1, 0))
> [:ok, :ok, :ok]
```

Or just use `all?` directly:

```elixir
Enum.all?(foo, &elem(&1, 0) == :ok)
> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
  def check_ok([]), do: true
  def check_ok([{:ok, _} | tail]), do: check_ok(tail)
  def check_ok(_), do: false
```

As long as `:ok` is found in each element of the list, the empty list will eventually match(clause #1) and return true.  Otherwise, when something other than `:ok` is found, the recursion will end immediately and the function will return false(clause #3).